# can i run a rails application without installing the rails environment on my mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have to make few UI changes for a rails application. Just to check those changes in browser do i have to setup whole rails env.
Is there any other way to get that.

I have rails env set on developers computers on same network.

Comment: You can. Use [`docker`](https://www.docker.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Great to know that you are working on an Rails application \m/. To answer your question:

1. Yes, you can definitely access a Rails application from your system. For Example, say there is a different machine that has the rails server running(example is: abc.def.g.h:8000), if both your system and this server system are on the same network, you can easily access the rails application using the ipaddress and the port by entering abc.def.g.h:8000 on your browser's address.

However, you may not be able to change anything at the code level. You can do this only on the server machine. or through some other ways (example access the server machine using TeamViewer to connect your machine to the server machine)

Answer (score 0):

Not needed, you can access your dev computes of same network. add ip/port of dev computer in url and it will work.

Comment: the changes that i will make on my pc how they will be reflected on his ip.

Comment: opss. you mean. you have changes but not rails env. and other have rails env. and you wants like other can see your changes !! . In this scenario it will not help buddy. That is not possible.